# scala - cache and reload a future which will become invalid later

Tags: scala, concurrency, future

```
  private class FutMemorizer[T](valid: T => Boolean)(f: () => Future[T]) {

    private val ref = new AtomicReference[Promise[T]]

    @scala.annotation.tailrec
    final def get(): Future[T] = {
      val nullableRef = ref.get()
      val valid = checkPromise(ref.get())
      if(valid) {
        nullableRef.future
      } else {
        val p = Promise[T]
        val success = ref.compareAndSet(nullableRef, p)
        if(success) {
          p.completeWith(f())
          p.future
        } else {
          get()
        }
      }
    }

    private def checkPromise(nullable: Promise[T]) = {
      nullable != null && {
        nullable.future.value match {
          case None => true // future is not complete all caller should wait
          case Some(Success(v)) => valid(v)
          case _ => false
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

I am implementing an `Future` memorizer that only cache a `valid` future value.

> It must meet following requirements
>
> 1. `Futures` created by `f` never executed paralleled
> 2. `get` never return a invalid value (once `invalid` recall `f()` to reload)

Is my implementation correct ?

Is there a more `functional` or simpler way to do this (because I hardly prove correntness of mime)?

Comment: So what happens when the value in future hapens to be invalid? Call `f` once again to see if the next future is valid?

Comment: @Kolmar Yes, that's what I am expecting

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just find [spray-cache](https://github.com/spray/spray/blob/master/spray-caching/src/main/scala/spray/caching/LruCache.scala) already have this feature

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understand this is wrong:

```
p.completeWith(f())
```

The caller gets a future the value of which is (or will be sometimes) that of the future returned by `f()`, but it's not checked anywhere that this value satisfies or will satisfy `valid(...)`; same for other callers that came while the resulting future returned by `f()` is in progress if it takes time. It's only when result of `f()` completes will the next caller probably start "fixing" it.

I would probably go about fixing this problem the following way (see the `fixed` method), with some stylistic changes:

```
class FutMemorizer[T](valid: T => Boolean)(f: () => Future[T]) {

  private val ref = new AtomicReference[Future[T]]

  @tailrec
  final def get: Future[T] = {
    val current = ref.get
    if (current != null && isValid(current)) current
    else {
      val p = Promise[T]
      val pf = p.future
      if (ref.compareAndSet(current, pf)) {
        p.completeWith(fixed(f))
        pf
      } else get
    }
  }

  private def fixed(f: () => Future[T]): Future[T] =
    f() flatMap { t =>
      if (valid(t)) Future.successful(t) else fixed(f)
    }

  private def isValid(future: Future[T]) = 
    future.value match {
      case None => true // future is not complete all caller should wait
      case Some(Success(v)) => valid(v)
      case _ => false
    }
}
```

As for your question about a more functional way of doing it I *guess* `f` and `valid` having effects on the external state and basing their computations on it (which I guess is the point of having a memorizer with invalidation) would seriously hinder it.

Comment: Thanks for you reply.   `get` actually read remote resource, like an `refresh oauth access token`, `valid` is time senstive.  So the actually situation is I am trying to read or refresh an `access_token`, it must not be called concurrently. Do you know how Could I simplify my code ?